# Why is not well positioned among two from a list?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://www.paulvanesch.com/index.php/blog/)

I have listed above and unfortunately elements (some) are not positioned correctly ...

I want to be subducted (fixed)

Look at the picture below to understand more clearly what I mean.

[image]

**CODE HTML:**

```
<ul class="new-list">
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/unlimited-2015-photo-impression.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image1_.jpeg" width="145" alt="kranz"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/marlene-dumas-image-as-burden-fondation.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image5_.jpeg" width="145" alt="thumb"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/unlimited-2015-photo-impression.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image1_.jpeg" width="145" alt="kranz"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/marlene-dumas-image-as-burden-fondation.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image5_.jpeg" width="145" alt="thumb"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/unlimited-2015-photo-impression.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image1_.jpeg" width="145" alt="kranz"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/marlene-dumas-image-as-burden-fondation.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image5_.jpeg" width="145" alt="thumb"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/unlimited-2015-photo-impression.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image1_.jpeg" width="145" alt="kranz"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/marlene-dumas-image-as-burden-fondation.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image5_.jpeg" width="145" alt="thumb"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/marlene-dumas-image-as-burden-fondation.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image5_.jpeg" width="145" alt="thumb"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/marlene-dumas-image-as-burden-fondation.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image5_.jpeg" width="145" alt="thumb"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/unlimited-2015-photo-impression.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image1_.jpeg" width="145" alt="kranz"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://paulvanesch.blogspot.ro/2015/06/marlene-dumas-image-as-burden-fondation.html?view=flipcard" target="_blank"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/image5_.jpeg" width="145" alt="thumb"></a></li>
<ul>
</ul></ul>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.new-list{
  text-align:center;
}
.new-list li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Can you please tell me what the problem is and what is not good?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `.new-list{text-align:center; padding:0;margin:0}` and `.new-list li{display:inline-block;padding:0;margin:0}` ?

Comment: Your problem is that you have line breaks between some `<li>`s. These generate spaces (with varying font size). Remove them or comment them out.

Comment: An empty `<ul></ul>` on the last two lines - why?

Answer (score 0):

This will have to do with white space between `<li>` elements. In your other rows further down, they are all part of one line. In your top two rows, it is one line that was broken at the end and the white space to make them centered is what is throwing this off.

I don't have a solution to your problem at the moment but that is the cause.

Comment: @cimmanon The question is not about white space between elements. That it was the solution is not obvious; perhaps only to some. That is why I didn't vote to close and you shouldn't be guessing as to what I was thinking.